# Can Google Analytics tell me where in a country traffic is coming from?

Tags: google-analytics, geolocation

In a nutshell, I'd like to see what *city* traffic is coming from. Currently I can only seem to figure out how to detect which *country* traffic is coming from.

Does anyone know if there is a way to drill down into a country to see where traffic is coming from with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just click on a country on the map the see a city view.

Comment: Or 'Visitors > Map overlay' from the sidebar menu.

Comment: The figures by city aren't reliable: for example mine is recorded is being in the capital city which is three hours drive away, because that is where my ISP is based, even though I am in a different city.